# Problem working with python List in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I need some help working with a `list` of `WebElements` from a table using Selenium in Python.

The specific problem I'm having is iterating through my list.
When I get the `WebElements` from the table the list initially matches the order being displayed on screen, but I need to wait for staleness and then the list gets messed up.

Basically my text from my list might look something like:

```
elementList = ["some title-part 3.mp3", "some title-part 4.mp3", "Some Title, Part 1", "Some Other Title, Part X"]
```

I'm trying to rename the `.mp3` files to their appropriate titles read from a file.
The initial loop, `i=0`, works perfectly for `"some title-part 3.mp3"`, but after waiting for staleness the elements change index. It looks like the index of `"some title-part 4.mp3"` becomes `elementList[0]` but `i` has incremented to `i=1` so it finds `"Some Title, Part 1"` or something else and therefore passes over the `.mp3` file at the top of the list.

I've tried adding buffer files to the top of the list to move my test files down the list, but it always seems to iterate in a way that it misses the next `.mp3` file.

Here's my code so far:

```
# where element list.text = ["some title-part 3.mp3", "some title-part 4.mp3", "Some Title, Part 1", "Some Other Title, Part X"]
elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, myTablePath)))

for i in range(len(elements)):
    if (".mp3" in element.text):
        renameElementTitle(elements[i]) # this navs away from the list

        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(element)) # then it needs to wait for staleness 
        elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, myTablePath)))
        # the list gets reordered in some fashion after this and doesn't iterate right
```

I was thinking of trying something different with the list like using `list.pop()`, but still not sure how to make that work.

```
# Something like this?
elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, myTablePath)))
someIndex = 0
while(len(elements) > 0):
    if (".mp3" in element[someIndex].text):
        correctTitle = getCorrectTitleFromList(element[someIndex]) # store the correct title to find the new index
        renameElementTitle(elements[someIndex]) # rename the title like normal

        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(element))
        elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, myTablePath)))

        renamedTitleIndex = elements.somehowFindIndexOf(correctTitle) # find the index of the new title text
        elements.pop(renamedTitleIndex) # pop that specific index
    else:
        elements.pop(someIndex)
    someIndex++
```

Or am I overthinking this and there's an easy to keep everything in the same order when updating the list after the title has been updated?

Comment: Why do you have to `renameElementTitle` as you scan? Can't you scan first, generate the complete `to_be_renamed` list and then iterate over the said list with `renameElementTitle`? In that case you don't have to worry about order, you can check with `driver.find_element_by` for each item in your list.

Comment: This might be what I need to do. Everything I've tried isn't working, or causes other problems. I can see the logic in building a list of everything that needs to be updated first, then iterating through it. I could also try using `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[contains(text(),"' + titleToBeRenamed + '")]')` but I've had weird results with searching by text.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your issue correct (that after renaming element, it changes it's order in DOM, but not on the screen), I usually solving it by sorting element list by location.

After renaming item and waiting for staleness, you just wait for element visibility (as you did) and then re-init elements array via sorting function.

It would guarantee, that visible element with index would be always in correct order (and not rely on DOM order)

```py
def get_y_location_key(element):
    location = element.location
    return location['y']

        #your code before staleness

        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(element))
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, myTablePath)))
        elements = sorted(link_element, key=get_y_location_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    # ["some title-part 3.mp3", "some title-part 4.mp3", "Some Title, Part 1", "Some Other Title, Part X"] 
    elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, myTablePath)))
    edited_list = []
    for element in elements:
        if ".mp3" in element.text:
            element.text = element.text[:-4]     
        edited_list.append(element.text)
```

Output: ['some title-part 3', 'some title-part 4', 'Some Title, Part 1', 'Some Other Title, Part X']

Then you can sort.

```
edited_list.sort()
```

Output: ['Some Other Title, Part X', 'Some Title, Part 1', 'some title-part 3', 'some title-part 4']

Of coure this approach is not limited to only extract `.text`
You could edit whole objects if neccesary.